# iOS CollectionView Help (saving current state)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am making an iOS app in Swift and I am running into a obstacle I seem to be stuck on.  I have a collectionview populated by an string array, which are the names of the images I am populating the image within the collectionview cells:

```
var tableData: [String] = ["cricket1.png", "cricket1.png", "cricket1.png"]
```

I've linked up the images to the collectionview with the following code:

```
//How many cells there are is equal to the amount of items in tableData (.count property)
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

//Linking up collectionView with tableData
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CricketCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CricketCell
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

When I have the user tap the cell, the image goes from cricket1.png to cricket2.png:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("Cell selected")

        var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CricketCell


            if cell.imgCell.image == UIImage(named:"cricket1.png"){
                var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CricketCell
                cell.imgCell.image =  UIImage(named:"cricket2.png")

            }
```

Now.. here is where I am having trouble.  I am currently trying to save data in tableData, however when I do, it always saves it as `["cricket1.png", "cricket1.png", "cricket1.png"]`.  Even if the image has been tapped and changed to "cricket2.png".  Even if all the images on the screen is cricket2.png, when I save tableData, it saves it as `["cricket1.png", "cricket1.png", "cricket1.png"]`.  I am aware it is because I am storing the variable tableData I declared earlier, but is there any way I can grab a string array of what is on the screen/the current state of the collectionview?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: show do you save the data exactly? The thing is, you didn't change any data in tableData based on what I see.

Comment: I didnt change anything in tableDat.  But when I am running the app, and I tap the cell, the image (which is cricket1.png, and comes from tableData array) changes to another image.  When you change the image, it doesnt update the array in tableData.  How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the data in the array yourself.  It's independent from image.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Cell selected")

    //1: Get the index for which data in array you need to update
    let index = indexPath.row

    //I don't think this comparison may server your purpose. When you new an UIImage object, it's a different one than the original image.  You may want to just compare the data
    let unSelectedImage = "cricket1.png"
    if self.tableData[index] != unselectedImage {
         //2: Update data in array
         var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CricketCell
         let selectedImageName = "cricket2.png"
         self.tableData[index] = selectedImageName
         cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageName)
    } 

}
```

So in this case, even you refresh the table, image will loading according to the new tableData.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This worked amazing.  All I had to do was change != to ==.  You saved me hours of stress on my final school project haha.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to upvote.  I just joined so it wouldn't let me do it until I earned enough "xp" hahah

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that u use another property to hold the state of the cell. For example,

`var selectedState = [true, false, true, true, true]`

Upon tapping the image, update the image and selectedState array accordingly.
For example,

`if selectedState[indexPath.row] {
    cell.imgCell.image == UIImage(named:"cricket1.png")
 else {
    cell.imgCell.image =  UIImage(named:"cricket2.png")
 }`

Once you are ready to grab the state of the tapped cells, you can use the selectedState array variable.

You can't use the cell to persist any state as the cell can get dequeued by collectionView and may lost its state as you scroll.

Hope this helps.